# Why does my crontab not run cron.daily scripts?

Tags: cron

My crontab file is in /etc/
I have a folder: /etc/cron.daily with dbBackup_sh, logrotate and tmpreaper
I run these 3 scripts manually every day with no problem.

My crontab will not run the daily scripts.
**What is wrong with my crontab file?**

```
SHELL=/bin/sh
PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin
23 * * * * root cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.hourly
1 4 * * * root  cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.daily
48 3 * * 7 root cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.weekly
25 3 8 * * root cd / && run-parts --report /etc/cron.monthly
```

Output of `ls -la /etc/cron.daily/`:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 102 Feb 22 2021 .placeholder 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 449 Mar 29 2022 dbBackup_sh 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 377 Feb 28 2021 logrotate 
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4006 Sep 6 2019 tmpreaper
```

Comment: Can you post contents of `cron.daily` and your scripts?

Comment: Yes please include the output of `ls -la /etc/cron.daily/` in your question.

Comment: ... there are also naming conventions for `run-parts` (in particular, no "dot extensions" iirc)

Comment: @steeldriver it's considerably more complex. It never made sense to me: [How do you use the run-parts command?](https://superuser.com/a/719493)

Answer (score 3):

The scripts inside `/etc/cron.daily/` has to be executable to run. *(This has the additional benefit, that if you want to temporarily disable a cron job here, just unset the executable bit for that particular script.)*

One of your files (`dbBackup_sh`) does not have the executable bit set. Fix this with:

```
sudo chmod +x /etc/cron.daily/dbBackup_sh
```

Also, as @steeldriver mentions, the names must only include alphanumeric characters, dash (`-`) and underscore (`_`) - which is also the case for you.

To me, it would seem all scripts will run after you fix permissions for `dbBackup_sh`.

A good way to test if a cron script has been running is to include a line that touches a file. You could add to each script: *(The variable `$0` expands to the script name.)*

```
touch "/dev/shm/${0##*/}"
```

Then, look inside the folder `/dev/shm` tomorrow, and check if the files are there.

Comment: You will be able to verify that that was the problem by looking in `/var/log/syslog`.

Comment: I see, yes x is missing. I just fixed that as you suggested.
We'll see what happens tomorrow.
Thank You.